# Ubuntu 14.04 can't move files from phone storage to computer

Tags: files, android, shotwell

I have a HTC One m8, and when I plug it in it shows up in Files as "Android Phone". It shows my internal storage automatically, and at the top it says "Contains digital photos Shotwell". But the issue is, when I try to move a file from my phone's internal storage to a place on my computer (drag and dropping), I get an error and it doesn't work. It says there was an error copying it to file into /home/user/... And if I press show more details it says this: Error getting file: -6: Not Supported. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I have seen others having this problem but no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed gmtp (`sudo apt-get install gmtp`), connected my phone, switched it to PTP not MTP. Opened gmtp, connected device through there, and it worked.

Comment: where did you switch from MTP to PTP? Can't find this on the One Max...

Answer (score 1):

1) Close Shotwell

2) Open Nautilus

[image: l1]

3) Select your source device from the left column

4) click File, then New Tab

5) Select your target directory from the left column

6) Go to the original tab. Select all the files you wish to move. right click on one of the highlighted files and choose cut.

7) Go to the target tab. Right click in an empty space in the folder and choose paste.

Comment: Still got the same error. I tried running nautilus as root, but my android's storage wasn't listed there, so the only way I could access it was from Shotwell. What's weird is I can delete files off my phone in shotwell, and put files from my computer on my phone, but I can't do the opposite.

Comment: Check the permissions on your target folder and insure that you are allowed to write to it.

Comment: Yea I can write to it. It's also worth mentioning that I get the error, but it does create the file - with nothing in it. I tried moving over something that was 10mb and the same file name popped in my target folder, but I got the error and the file that was created was 0 bytes.

Comment: @Zordid There's no need to be rude. That wasn't clear at the time I answered the question (at least to me). You might note that the best answers rise to the top here and you can downvote an answer if you feel it's not useful.

Comment: It it Android 5.1 by chance?

Answer (score -1):

on the phone, go to settings>storage and then open the menu and select "usb commputer connection".set it to mtp, and try it and then see if setting it to ptp does anything. It seems like it is set to the original ptp type method, but not the compatibility version.

Comment: Didn't work, though thanks for the suggestion. When I do this, it opens up in shotwell, though it's all my pictures. Dragging and dropping works, but I'm trying to get other files to my computer's storage (not pictures).

Comment: try installing dolphin and then just open the directory for the phone and copy the files that way, shotwell literally never worked for me

Comment: Probably something on my end, but I don't see my device listed on dolphin.

Comment: is it set to mtp? Also, is the cable an oem? In the past I've found that a lot of aftermarket cables do NOT work for any kind of large scale data transfer

Comment: Yeah it's mtp. The cable is from LG, though I am using an HTC phone. I don't think that's the issue though, as transfering files from my computer to the phone works, but the opposite doesn't.

Comment: Just figured it out! I install gmpt, plugged my phone in, and connected my phone to gmpt. I tried mtp, but I couldn't transfer files completely, as I got errors and some files wouldn't download.  I switched it to PTP, and it worked through gmpt :). Thanks for your help though, I really appreicate it.